# WebPack + SASS : How to generate relative image path?

Tags: sass, relative-path, sass-loader, webpack-3, extracttextwebpackplugin

I am trying to set up a web application behind an Apache vhost which acts as proxy (proxyPass) in order to add a contextPath. Only the vhost has to know this contextPath of course.

Everything is ok, except the background-images which are not loaded. The reason is simple :

**SASS image URLs are absolute and don't contain the contextPath.**

If the generated URLs in the final CSS were relative, images should be loaded correctly.

**How to use SASS/Webpack in order to generate relative path then ?**

---

*Notes:*

Whatever I use in SASS file, absolute or relative path, the final output is always absolute. I currently use :

- Webpack 3
- node-sass 4.5.3
- sass-loader 6.0.6
- extract-text-webpack-plugin 3.0.0

I don't use any file-loader (I tryed too but change nothing) and just copy all images in the dist directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to set the **url option to false** in the css-loader (see [css-loader documentation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader)). Moreover, as soon as we use relative paths in SASS sources, we need a file-loader too, with emitFile to false if we use CopyWebpackPlugin who already in charge to copy those files in dist directory.

```
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [{
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: { url: false }
          }, {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }]
        })
      }, {
        test: /\.(png|svg)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]',
          options: {
            emitFile: false
          }
        }]
      }
```